# involution of a riemann surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've have found in the book GEOMETRY OF ALGEBRAIC CURVES by Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths that if $\pi: C^{'}\rightarrow C$ it's a double unramified cover of a complex riemann surface named $C$ that we can define the sheet interchange involution $\tau: C^{'} \rightarrow C^{'}$. Someone can tell me how does $\tau$ act on the points of $C^{'}$?

Comment: It swaps the two points lying above a given point.

Comment: so, for example, if $q_{1},q_{2}\in \pi^{-1}(p)$ we have $\tau(q_{1})=q_{2}$ and so on ?