# Involution on divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $\pi:C^{'} \rightarrow C$ is an unramified double cover of a complex riemann surface. Let $\tau$ the involution sheet exchange.
If $E$ is a divisor on $C^{'}$ What is the definition of $\tau(E)$?

Comment: My question is simple but i cannot find a reference about involution so i've put this question to learn a definition of that. Someone can suggest some reference about involution?

Comment: You've already been informed what $\tau$ does: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115513/involution-of-a-riemann-surface

$\tau(E)$ is just the image of the divisor under $\tau$.

Comment: so for example if $E=nq_1$ where $q_1,q_2 \in \pi(p)$ $\tau(E)=nq_2$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.